# PRISM Command to include sender, OnNavigated command to include WebBrowser sender

Tags: c#, wpf, command, prism

I would like to include the 'sender' object in my ViewModel's DelegateCommand.

```
<WebBrowser>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Navigated">
            <prism:InvokeCommandAction  
                        Command="{Binding NavigatedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</WebBrowser>


private DelegateCommand<NavigationEventArgs> _onNavigated;
public DelegateCommand<NavigationEventArgs> NavigatedCommand => _onNavigated ?? (_onNavigated = new DelegateCommand<NavigationEventArgs>(OnNavigated, (e) => true));

private void OnNavigated(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
//TODO add code to access the WebBrowser.Document property
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
private DelegateCommand<WebBrowser, NavigationEventArgs> _onNavigated;
```

What is the Delegate Command?

Comment: Are you sure that you want a command? If you need the control, you're ui-stuff with it, so just put that in code-behind (the event gets the sender).

Comment: @Haukinger PRISM MVVM. not old codebehind.

Comment: What does your command do? What does it need the `sender` for? Code-behind is perfectly fine for doing view-related stuff.

Comment: Access to the WebBrowser control object would expose the Document property.

Comment: What prevents you from putting the `Document` in the `CommandParameter`?

Comment: Good idea: but CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Document, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type WebBrowser}}}"
                        only sends NavigationEventArgs, even if change the Command to accept T as object

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `i:InvokeCommandAction` instead of `prism:InvokeCommandAction`.

I don't know, *why* the prism variant does not work with `CommandParameter`, but the interactivity one does...

View:

```
<WebBrowser>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Navigated">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NavigatedCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Document, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type WebBrowser}}}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</WebBrowser>
```

View Model:

```
public SomeWindowViewModel()
{
    NavigatedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>( x => { /* x is the browser's Document here */ } );
}

public DelegateCommand<object> NavigatedCommand { get; }
```